# Can you nest a media query inside another media query?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, media-queries

I have a safari only issue that only appears when the device width is tablet or lower "max-width:1024px". Is it possible to nest a media query inside another media query?

```
@media screen and (max-width:1024px){
     @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
     { 
        /* Safari and Chrome */
        ul#squareImgUL{
            bottom: 10px;
        } 

        /* Safari only override */
        ::i-block-chrome,ul#squareImgUL{
            bottom: 0px !important;
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't but pairing them up works fine too

```
@media screen and (max-width:1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){

}
```

Comment: The linked duplicate says that you can nest media queries or is there a difference in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can not nest the media queries but you can use the and operator

```
@media screen and (max-width:1024px) and 
    (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
...
```

Comment: When adding max-width in using "and " the the styling stops working.

 @media screen and (max-width:1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
     { 
        /* Safari and Chrome */
        ul#squareImgUL{
            bottom: 10px;
        } 

        /* Safari only override */
        ::i-block-chrome,ul#squareImgUL{
            bottom: 0px !important;
        } 
    }

Comment: Not clear with what you are saying. Please elaborate

Comment: I just tried adding both media queries together using "and" and it breaks the styling.

Comment: There was a small glitch. @media screen was added twice. I have updated the code. Try now.

Comment: You have too many `and`'s

Comment: Thanks. Probably not my day today :)

Comment: fixed it to avoid any confusion to those using these answers.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your help :)

Comment: Somebody voted negative for the answer - Can I please know the reason?